# convert DNF to CNF for SAT solver

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have a logic to feed to SAT solver

```
(a1&&b1)||(a2&&b2)||(a3&&b3)||(a4&&b4)||(a5&&b5)
```

to feed to SAT solver which accepts CNF

I tried wolfram alpha to convert it into CNF but it's way too complicated to understand than the DNF. the original semantic is that, A and B intersects on one of the columns. which is why I think DNF is more readable

is there any way to incorporate some additional boolean variables to simplify it and convert it to CNF ?

the ultimate target is to maintain a relatively readable CNF

======ammend
the whole context is that I am trying to express Einstein's puzzle using CNF, I find some of the clauses are difficult to express using CNF.

Comment: Why would you convert a DNF to a CNF then apply the CNF to a SAT solver?  A DNF is a solved expression.  The best the SAT solver could do is just give you back one of the terms of the DNF.

Comment: So do you get my answer?

Comment: @zinking: What does not work? I gave you an equi-satisfiable CNF, using extra variables, which answers your question as you have stated. I'm not going to dig through your code, but if you used my answer exactly as it is the problem must be elsewhere, since I've re-checked my proof and I'm sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so what you **actually** want is to convert the given clause to an equi-satisfiable CNF, not to solve it nor to simply convert it to CNF.

Just create new boolean variables $p_{1..5}$.

Note that $a_k \land b_k \to p_k \equiv \neg a_k \lor \neg b_k \lor p_k$ and $p_k \to a_k \land b_k \equiv ( \neg p_k \lor a_k ) \land ( \neg p_k \lor b_k )$.

Thus by appending these two CNFs for each $k$ you get $p_k \equiv a_k \land b_k$ in any satisfying assignment.

After that the original clause can be replaced by $p_1 \lor \cdots \lor p_5$.

Comment: let's assume only p1. and (a,b,p) could be (T,F,F).  first half is true because b is F, second half is true because P is F. but obviously A^B = F.  so why would this work?

Comment: @zinking: Erm your example supports the claim that it works. Specifically, $a \land b = \bot = p$.

Comment: I didn't get, but P is F, why it works, I need A^B=T

Comment: @zinking: No you don't. Your question requires an **equisatisfiable** CNF, not a **true** CNF. You want it such that the original has a satisfying assignment **iff** the translated one has.